# Is there a way to browse Ubuntu files with a GUI instead of command line?

Tags: user-interface, command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04

Is there a way to browse Ubuntu files with a GUI instead of command line?

I'd like to be able to search around my Ubuntu server in a way similar to being able to view files on any Mac or PC visually with back and forwards arrows, folders, etc. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Yes, this would require the installation of XWindow and then a desktop environment to run on top of it. Most Ubuntu installs will have this type of setup as part of the default install. You may have selected a minimal install by mistake, so you only have the 'shell'.

Answer (score 1):

**Winscp** can help you do that . It's usually used to copy file from linux2windows or windows2linux ,but it can browse file on linux too.

ps:winscp don't need x installed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using MC.
It's a text based file manager.

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```